# Qt stop key events for a short period for a game loop

Tags: c++, qt, keyboard-events, game-loop

I am overriding keyPressEvent to move a player across a QGraphicsScene. The player has an animation which takes 1000ms (which should complete before continuing).

My problem is that if the user holds down the key it will send loads of events and it actually causes a noticeable lag. Is there any way that I can temporarily disable event listening other that setting some boolean?

To further the question; I have a game loop, and all movement should happen in intervals of e.g. 1000ms (think old games where all players move on the same tick - everything stays in sync). Unless the user clicks at the exact moment they will have to wait for the next tick for their move to appear. So the question here is how can I buffer a user press up to e.g. 200ms before the tick, and the moment the tick happens it executes the most recent press (up, down, left, right).

Or am I approaching this wrong?

Comment: I have no experience in gamedev whatsoever but for the first question setting boolean seems like the best option. As for the second question you can create an object for holding only one key event, and when you started "movement" you just write there first key event and discard all others

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like maybe what you want to do is make your keyPressEvent() callback method to be extremely lightweight; i.e. it should do nothing other than set a variable indicating what key the user has pressed:

```
void MyClass :: keyPressEvent(QKeyEvent * keyEvent)
{
   // all we'll do for now is remember what the user pressed (overwriting any previously-cached value)
   this->userPressedKey = key->key();  
   keyEvent->accept();
}

void MyClass :: tick()  // called every 200mS or whatever
{
   if (this->userPressedKey != Qt::Key_Unknown)
   {
      processKeyPressPerMyGameLogic(this->userPressedKey);
      this->userPressedKey = Qt::Key_Unknown;  // clear the state in preparation for the next tick() call
   }
   doOtherGameLogicHere();
}
```

If you want the user to be able to do multiple key-events per turn rather than just one, you could replace `this->userPressedKey` (currently a member variable of type `int`) with a `QSet<int>` or similar.

Comment: `QSet` doesn't save information about which event came first, `QVector` will do

Comment: @sfk92fksdf The problem with QVector is that if the user is holding down a key and thus the app receives "loads of key events", as the questioner describes, then at the end the QVector will contain loads of entries, and the user will be back to his original problem.  I agree that keeping information about the order in which events are received could be useful, though; with the appropriate data structure (or a QVector and an insert-only-if-not-already-present algorithm) that could be achieved.